I am getting error like element not interactable
I tried to capture XPath and click on them but I am getting error like element not interactable.
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
driver.get("https://dummy-tickets.com/buyticket");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

WebElement drp=driver.findElement(By.name("departure[]"));
drp.click();

//or//

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='departure[]']")).click();


I have tested it locally and I don't have an error.
You could also try to scroll it into view:
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", drp);
Thread.sleep(500);

Please also refer to this explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67479562/5126192

I have tried your code and found that the given webelement By.name("departure[]") is found more than once in UI
So i changed the Xpath with indices to fix this issue - By.xpath("(//input[@name='departure[]'])[1]")
Here is the working code FYR
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    driver.get("https://dummy-tickets.com/buyticket");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    WebElement drp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='departure[]'])[1]"));
    drp.click();

I also attached output screenshot for your reference
