# Click an element if it is present and click it

Tags: vba, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click a web element if it is present and for that I am using the following code

```
Set btn = bot.FindElementById("F", Raise:=False)
If Not bot.FindElementById("F", Raise:=False) Is Nothing Then
    bot.FindElementById("F").Click
Else
End If
```

but when I run the code I get the error

> element not interact-able

Comment: Can you share the url? Does it make a difference with a longer wait? And have a look through these explanations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119081/how-do-you-fix-the-element-not-interactable-exception these detail other possibilities like another element obscuring your target.

Comment: Thanx for responding. I am sorry for not being able to share URL as it is confidential. But the element is a radio button which occasionally comes on the page. What i want is want is that when it comes i may click it by above code and when it does not come my code should do nothing. But what actually happens is that when the element appears I am able to click the element . but then problem arises when the element do not appear on other occasion then it says element not found. Ideally it should pass without doing anything. Pls help

Comment: _element not found_ is not the same as _element not interactable_ If you have set btn into a variable why are you not testing if that variable is Nothing and clicking if not?   _If Not btn Is Nothing Then btn.click_  ?

Comment: I have tried the solution but when the radio button is not present I am again gettin msg element not visible. Elemen t is not interactable