# Failed to Read Marionette Port with selenium docker container in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, docker, selenium, firefox, aws-lambda

I have the following dockerfile with app code:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y \
    Xvfb \
    wget \
    gtk3 \
    dbus-glib \
    libpci \
    unzip \
    gcc \
    openssl-devel \
    zlib-devel \
    libffi-devel \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    alsa-lib-devel \
    # I think needed for pandas
    libxml2 \
    libxml2-devel \
    g++ \
    yum -y clean all
RUN yum -y groupinstall development

WORKDIR /opt

RUN wget -O- "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest-ssl&os=linux64&lang=en-US" | tar -jx -C /usr/local/

# Borrowed from here: https://github.com/aws-samples/container-web-scraper-example/blob/master/code/Dockerfile
RUN ln -s /usr/local/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox


RUN wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.31.0/geckodriver-v0.31.0-linux64.tar.gz
RUN tar -xf geckodriver-v0.31.0-linux64.tar.gz
RUN ls -lta
RUN rm geckodriver-v0.31.0-linux64.tar.gz

RUN chmod +x geckodriver
RUN export DISPLAY=:99
RUN Xvfb -ac -nolisten inet6 :99 &

WORKDIR /var/task

# Install selenium
COPY lambda_reqs.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r lambda_reqs.txt

# Copy lambda's main script
COPY app.py .

CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

app.py

```
# app.py
import os

import boto3
from io import StringIO

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

import pandas as pd

executable_path = '/opt/geckodriver'

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--single-process")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,
                           executable_path='/opt/geckodriver'
                           service_log_path=os.path.devnull,
                           )


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """
    Invoke AWS Lambda Function
    :param event:
    :param context:
    :return:
    """

    # More sample code than actual
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    element_text = driver.page_source
```

When I go to try and run the container in AWS Lambda console I get the following:

```
[ERROR] TimeoutException: Message: Failed to read marionette port

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path='/opt/geckodriver', service_log_path=os.path.devnull)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 177, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 275, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 365, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

I've been googling around trying to find of ways to get around this or address the issue, but I'm a bit stumped so I figured I would just post and ask directly if there was a way to address the marionette port issue here.

Side Note:
I've tried doing some of work use chrome and the chromedriver, but I get issues that are referenced here: [ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable: element has zero size appears since upgrade to chromedriver 83](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62003082/elementnotinteractableexception-element-not-interactable-element-has-zero-size) and I can't seem to install chrome 8.1 via dockerfile

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @jClean, I'm facing the same issue. Any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

The following arguments:

```
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--single-process")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
```

aren't relevant to ***geckodriver***.

Remove the arguments and rerun your test.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I removed those arguments, redeployed to AWS Lambda and re-ran the tests. I received the same error exactly shown above.