# I'm using selenium to scrape a local web

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to upload a file using 'upload' button. after that a window will appear but I can't find the exact ID from HTML code. here is the screen shots and my code:
[image]

[image]

`time.sleep(1)
element=driver.find_element_by_id("Upload-Action-Ico").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'File')]").send_keys("file path")`

Comment: Could you maybe give us the URL of the website?

Comment: It is a local website and will open only with specific ip's. here is the HTML code of this web site https://pastebin.pl/view/c0c3e73e

Comment: @aref Check out my answer and let me know whether it works for u.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the ID is 'file' so I think this should work

```py
time.sleep(1) 
element=driver.find_element_by_id("file").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try click on it and show the HTML code. There is a word "Button" or similar. Can you share me the url of the site?
I hope I can help you and excuse me for my english. (It isn't my mother-language)

Comment: there is no "Button"
here is the HTML code:
https://pastebin.pl/view/c0c3e73e

Answer (score 0):

The input field does not contain any text. And its `id` is explicitly mentioned in the html, so you can try `find_element_by_id`:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("file").send_keys("file path")
```

If this doesn't work for you, then you can try using the `xpath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='file']").send_keys("file path")
```

Comment: There is no such button in the html that u have provided. Are u sure that the html is right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to select files, and after that, you should click on the upload button.

```
filePath = os.getcwd()+'\img.jpg'
driver.find_element_by_id('Upload-Action-Ico').send_keys(filePath)
```

**os.getcwd()** : returns the current working directory.
img.jpg is located right next to the running script in the same directory.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: A possibility is that the element is currently unclickable because it is not visible. I tested this code, and works perfectly.

Comment: for more information, you can read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119081/how-do-you-fix-the-element-not-interactable-exception