# Selenium "“element not interactable exception" while using sendkeys on google Form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am trying to fill out the google form using selenium in python3.9

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSead7qqhVWP4m4q9Y71Wu9kr2lbCQXvY4ge0OdFg9fI0SQYYA/viewform

But I am getting an error at “element not interactable exception" at **form[0].send_keys('222')**

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from constants import FORM_URL, CHROME_DRIVER_LOCATION


class FillForm:
    def __init__(self, form = FORM_URL):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_LOCATION)
        self.driver.get(form)

    def fill_form(self, data: dict):
        form = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('exportInput')
        form[0].send_keys('222') #ERROR IS HERE
```

I read the thread b to solve the issue but seems like I am doing something wrong

Thread I read at the stackoverflow
[How do you fix the "element not interactable" exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119081/how-do-you-fix-the-element-not-interactable-exception)

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably calling `fill_form` right after initializing your `FillForm` object. Try adding an explicit wait to your `fill_form` function.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class FillForm:
    def __init__(self, form):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get(form)

    def fill_form(self, data: list, class_name='exportInput'):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'exportInput')))
        form = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name(class_name)
        for i, value in enumerate(data):
            form[i].send_keys(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just requires a wait. In Java

```
        WebElement inputElement1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[jsname='YPqjbf']"));
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(inputElement1));
        inputElement1.sendKeys("222");
```