# Type in a textbox via python: unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to locate an element using python selenium, and have the html below:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="University Search">
```

I couldn't locate where to type what I want to type.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\selenium\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/university-subject-rankings/2020/engineering-technology')

#<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="University Search">

text_area = driver.find_element_by_name('University Search')
text_area.send_keys("oxford university")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use [find_element_by_name](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-name) and yet this element has no `name` attribute defined. You need to look for the element with the specific `placeholder` attribute you are interested in - you can use [find_element_by_xpath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath) for this:

```
text_area = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='University Search']")
```

Also aside: When I open my browser, I don't see an element with "University Search" in the placeholder, only a search bar with "Site Search" -- but this might be a regional and/or browser difference.

Comment: This give an error: "selenium.common.exceptions.Element Not Interactable Exception: Message: element not interactable"

Comment: Most likely there's a popup hiding it... Standard solution is to use `ActionChains`, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119081/how-do-you-fix-the-element-not-interactable-exception

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you wait for the page to load using webdriver waits,click the popup and then proceed to target the element to send keys to.

```
driver.get('https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/university-subject-rankings/2020/engineering-technology')
driver.maximize_window()
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='OK, I agree']"))).click()
text_area=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR ,"td.uni-search.uni.sorting_disabled > div > input")))
text_area.send_keys("oxford university")
```

Imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Element to target

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="University Search">
```

Answer (score 1):

To send a *character sequence* to the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-control[placeholder='University search']").send_keys("oxford university")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='form-control' and @placeholder='University search']").send_keys("oxford university")
  ```

---

Ideally, to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/university-subject-rankings/2020/engineering-technology")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control[placeholder='University search']"))).send_keys("oxford university")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/university-subject-rankings/2020/engineering-technology")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control' and @placeholder='University search']"))).send_keys("oxford university")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: oxford]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Answer (score 0):

Very close, try the XPath when all else fails:

```
text_area = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='qs-rankings']/thead/tr[3]/td[2]/div/input")
```

You can copy the full/relative XPath to clipboard if you're inspecting the webpage's html.

Comment: What's the logic behind this code? Especially "[@id='qs-rankings']/thead/tr[3]/td[2]/div/input" part.

Comment: XPath is a query language used to navigate XML-like structures. By following the 'path' that leads to the `input` element starting from either the root element of the webpage or a relative one (the middle of the DOM structure), you can locate specific elements using this method. In this particular instance, you are looking at a relative XPath that begins at the `table` element with the id `qs-rankings`.