# Selenium & Python: Button not interactable; href="javascript:void(0);" onclick attribute

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to click this button

Next >>

My code is

```
next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Next')]")
next_page.click()
```

I have also tried using class name and onclick attribute name but they don't work either.

The code returns the error as ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.192).

Comment: share the HTML of the button. It might be set to disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the button is hidden and not accessible directly.  Maybe try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Next')]")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(next_page).click(next_page).perform()
```

[How do you fix the "element not interactable" exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119081/how-do-you-fix-the-element-not-interactable-exception)