# How to input a text on a textbox using selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm using Selenium with Python to input an address into a textbox within the Glovo page for Madrid. The code I wrote can be seen below, and the error I get is also copied after the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
  
url = 'https://glovoapp.com/es/es/madrid/'

# open browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# load page
driver.get(url)

# find field 
item = driver.find_element_by_class_name('address-input__container')

# select textbox and input text
time.sleep(2)
item.click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "el-input__inner"))
    )
item = driver.find_element_by_class_name('el-input__inner')
time.sleep(2)

item.send_keys('Calle')
```

The error I get is shown below.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

    item.send_keys('Calle')

      File "C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,

      File "C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)

      File "C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

      File "C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

`ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable`
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locator you are using is returning 2 different elements. See if this works

```
item = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='el-input__inner' and @data-test-id='address-input-autocomplete']")
item.send_keys("Calle")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It worked now. Just so I understand how you solved it... how did you notice that the locator was returning 2 different elements?

Answer (score 0):

Using various xpath for the element `address-input__container`and trying to click it is not working while automation and throws `ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable` You can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44119817/16452840). Applying the same and it works.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver.get("https://glovoapp.com/es/es/madrid/")
box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('address-input__container')
time.sleep(2)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(box).click(box).perform()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-test-id='address-input-autocomplete']").send_keys("SampleText")
```