# Selenium on Google Cloud

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

**My code works fine on my computer but in google cloud i am getting same error over and over again.
**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Set the path to the Chrome binary and ChromeDriver

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.binary_location = "...."
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920x1080")

# Start the Chrome browser

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# Navigate to the Google homepage

browser.get("https://www.google.com.tr")

search_box = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))
)
print(search_box)
\#EC.element_to_be_clickable

# Enter the search query and submit the form

search_box.send_keys("Python programming")
search_box.submit()

print(browser.title)
```

this is error that i had. It works fine on my local computer.

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable (Session info: headless chrome=112.0.5615.49) Stacktrace: \#0 0x555c82055a23 \<unknown\> \#1 0x555c81d83821 \<unknown\> \#2 0x555c81dba24c \<unknown\> \#3 0x555c81db9a66 \<unknown\> \#4 0x555c81de13c2 \<unknown\> \#5 0x555c81db5463 \<unknown\> \#6 0x555c81de158e \<unknown\> \#7 0x555c81df9d06 \<unknown\> \#8 0x555c81de1193 \<unknown\> \#9 0x555c81db3b5a \<unknown\> \#10 0x555c81db4c9e \<unknown\> \#11 0x555c8201775d \<unknown\> \#12 0x555c8201b60c \<unknown\> \#13 0x555c82024800 \<unknown\> \#14 0x555c8201c703 \<unknown\> \#15 0x555c81fef3c5 \<unknown\> \#16 0x555c8203f558 \<unknown\> \#17 0x555c8203f6e7 \<unknown\> \#18 0x555c8204d4b3 \<unknown\> \#19 0x7ff3aa79eea7 start_thread
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you fix the "element not interactable" exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119081/how-do-you-fix-the-element-not-interactable-exception)

Comment: Is that the [*full text* of the error/traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146)?

Comment: First off, do you have Chrome installed on the server? Second, why are you running it in headless mode (which you should be doing) while also setting the window size?

Comment: @SimonUnderwood I don't think that link provides anything useful to the OP, as they're already incorporating things suggested there into their code.

Comment: Is this GAE Flex environment?

Comment: @MattDMo I just try other suggestions that's why windows size was there but I tried this code without setting window size as well. I have google chrome on my google cloud server if want to get just title of the browser(just for testing google chrome) it works fine. But if I want get element from page it just couldn't find it.