# Can you interact with the like button on Instagram using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, instagram

I've been trying to like the posts in my feed by using Selenium but so far have had no luck

Here is my code:

```
like_buttons = chrome.find_elements_by_xpath("//article//section//button//*[@aria-label='Like']")
    for button in like_buttons:
        button.click()
        time.sleep(1)
```

I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Comment: I think this may help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119081/how-do-you-fix-the-element-not-interactable-exception

Comment: I tried the solutions on that page but didn't get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
like_buttons = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.XPATH, "//article//section//button//*[@aria-label='Like']"))
for button in like_buttons:
    button.click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Or this:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
like_buttons = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.XPATH, "//article//section//button//*[@aria-label='Like']"))
for button in like_buttons:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for your answer , on this line "like_buttons = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.XPATH, "//article//section//button//*[@aria-label='Like']"))
" it gave me unexpected argument error so i wrote the code like this "like_buttons = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//article//section//button//*[@aria-label='Like']")))" In the end it gave a TimeoutException error on that line.

Comment: Maybe i have the wrong xpath idk