# Element not interactable error : Selenium Python form automate filling

Tags: python, forms, selenium-webdriver, element, autofill

I am using Selenium to automate filling an online form. I have trouble with a checkbox. Here is the page elements list:

[page elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Txq.jpg)

When inspecting the checkbox, this element is identified:

Here is my script

```
checkbox = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "iCheck-helper")
checkbox.click()
```

So I can't find the ID for the element, I am using the class name instead. And I get the following error:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

So, I think this checkbox has multiple layers, and I may not use the right element??? not sure

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

I tried multiple approaches. Tried all the elements in the proximity, and they didn't work.

I also tried waiting, and time is not an issue, the page is fully loaded, I can see the checkbox.

Comment: You can try this [How do you fix the "element not interactable" exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119081/how-do-you-fix-the-element-not-interactable-exception)

Comment: That is an `<ins>` element.  It is not an `<input>` element, or a button, or a link, or any kind of element that can be clicked on...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your selector is correct (which seems to be the case based on what you've provided) there could a number of causes for an 'Element not interactable' error:

**Timing or Synchronisation issues**: The element is not yet present on the DOM or is not yet interact-able.

**Element is not visible or obscured**: Another element could be obscuring the element you're trying to interact with, or the element is not within the viewable area on the page.

**iFrame issues**: The element you're trying to interact with is nested within an iframe.

For the first two causes the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119081/how-do-you-fix-the-element-not-interactable-exception) suggested above might help. However, if the issue relates to an iframe, then you'll have to [switch to](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/handling-frames-in-selenium) the iframe within your script before interacting with any elements in it.

Based on your description, it seems there is some likelihood that an iframe is being used. Also the class names (e.g. iCheck-helper) give me an inkling that you might be dealing with an iframe, but that could just be coincidental. If iframes are implemented using the iframe tags (which is common), you can run a quick check by searching for 'iframe' in your dev tools under the elements tab.

If none of these work, you could try using execute_script() to toggle the checkbox on using js.

Comment: It is not an iframe, I chacked the source, no iframe tag. Also I used I used is_displayed(), the element is not displayed

Comment: Ok. You also mentioned you've tried using other elements in proximity - Have you tried: i) Using the selector for the input (type="checkbox") instead of the ins as suggested above? ii) tried move_to_element prior to clicking?

If neither of those work, then yes it's likely that your element is being obscured/overlapped as you suggested. In that case, you could use execute_script() to toggle the checkbox on using js.